# HTA / HTML Back button not working

Tags: html, onclick, return, back, hta

I have this very basic launcher:

```
<html>
<head>
<HTA:APPLICATION id="hwHTA"
applicationName="hyperHTA"
border="thin"
borderStyle="normal"
caption="yes"
maximizeButton="yes"
minimizeButton="yes"
showInTaskbar="no"
windowState="normal"
innerBorder="yes"
navigable="yes"
scroll="auto"
scrollFlat="yes"
singleInstance="yes" 
sysMenu="yes"
contextMenu="yes"
selection="yes" 
version="1.0" />
<title>Simple HTML Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<a href="m1.hta" target="_top">LINK</a>
</body>
</html>
```

And it launches this hta file:

```
<HTA:APPLICATION id="hwHTA"
applicationName="hyperHTA"
border="thin"
borderStyle="normal"
caption="yes"
maximizeButton="yes"
minimizeButton="yes"
showInTaskbar="no"
windowState="normal"
innerBorder="yes"
navigable="yes"
scroll="auto"
scrollFlat="yes"
singleInstance="yes" 
sysMenu="yes"
contextMenu="yes"
selection="yes" 
version="1.0" />
    <SCRIPT type="text/jscript">
        // Always Set Size Here to Avoid Flicker
        window.moveTo(100,100);
    </SCRIPT>
<body background = "Image.jpg">
<TITLE>Chip-set PC-Booster</TITLE>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        function RunFile() {
                window.open("website.com");
        }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        function RunFile2() {
        WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
        WshShell.Run("me1.exe", 1, false);
        }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        function RunFile3() {
        WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
        WshShell.Run("me2.exe", 1, false);
        }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        function RunFile4() {
        WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
        WshShell.Run("me13.exe", 1, false);
        }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        function RunFile5() {
        WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
        WshShell.Run("me15.exe", 1, false);
        }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        function RunFile6() {
        WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
        WshShell.Run("me16.exe", 1, false);
        }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        function RunFile7() {
        WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
        WshShell.Run("License.txt", 1, false);
        }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        function RunFile8() {
        WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
        WshShell.Run("FILEPATH", 1, false);
        }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        function RunFile9() {
        WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
        WshShell.Run("me19.exe", 1, false);
        }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        function RunFile10() {
        WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
        WshShell.Run("me25.exe", 1, false);
        }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        function RunFile11() {
        WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
        WshShell.Run("me23.exe", 1, false);
        }
    </script>
    <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="VBScript">
        Sub ExitProgram()
            window.close()
        End Sub
    </script>
<input type="button" value="   Goto the website   " name="run_button"  onClick="RunFile()"><p>
<input type="button" value="     Quick Optimise    " name="run_button"  onClick="RunFile2()"><p> 
<input type="button" value="       Full Optimise      " name="run_button"  onClick="RunFile3()"><p> 
<input type="button" value="       Quick restore      " name="run_button"  onClick="RunFile4()"><p>
<input type="button" value="       Deep restore      " name="run_button"  onClick="RunFile5()"><p>
<input type="button" value="        Turbo mode       " name="run_button"  onClick="RunFile6()"><p>
<input type="button" value="    View the licence    " name="run_button"  onClick="RunFile7()"><p>
<input type="button" value="Optimise the registry" name="run_button"  onClick="RunFile9()"><p>
<input type="button" value="    Edit the page file    " name="run_button"  onClick="RunFile10()"><p>
<input type="button" value="            Uninstall            " name="run_button"  onClick="RunFile11()"><p>
<input type="button" value="                 Exit                 " name="run_button"  onClick="ExitProgram()"><p>
<FORM><INPUT Type="button" VALUE="Back" onClick="history.go(-1);return true;"></FORM>
</body>
```

When the back button is pressed it doesn't do any thing. Can any one help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to replace the `onClick = "history.go (-1)` on onClick =" with `window.history.back ();` 
I've just checked how it works

Comment: I doesnt seem to be working i have just tried `<FORM><INPUT Type="button" VALUE="Back" onClick ="window.history.back ();"></FORM>`

Comment: Are you sure? I checked for this example that you have shown and by pressing a button returned me to the previous page

Comment: Have you tested it with the code above in the Question.

Comment: created two documents, one of them made ​​the switch to the other and the other's back button and pressing me back ozvraschalo on that page where I came from

Comment: try it yet <a href = "javascript:history.back()">Back to previous page</a>

Comment: When I click it nothing happens.

Comment: maybe I can not understand where you are using it though hta would have worked too

Comment: It is a hta document.

Comment: Thanks anyway for you help.